# How to get a list and put it into a form drop list

Tags: python, odoo

I have a model declared that have

```
class GuimarcLinechargerule(models.Model):
    _name = 'guimarc.linechargerule'

    line_type = fields.Char('line_type', required=True)
    loc = fields.Char('loc', required=True)
    prod_type = fields.Char('prod_type', required=True)
    cost_element = fields.Char('cost_element', required=True)
```

I want keep a list of `cost_element` and put it in a dropdown list in a form.

My class only has:

```
 cost_element = fields.Many2one('guimarc.linechargerule',string='cost_element')
```

However it comes to me just the IDs.

My form:

```
<form string="Fiance master cost" create="true" editable="top" delete="true">
   <sheet string="Finance Master Cost">
        <group>
            <group>
                <field name="cost_element"/>
                <field name="loc"/>
                <field name="cost"/>
                <field name="created_by"/>
                <field name="activate_date"/>
            </group>
        </group>
    </sheet>
</form>
```

So what I really want is get the list  of cost element from `guimarc.linecharrule` and put it as dropdown list for field `cost_element` when the form is called.

Answer (score 1):

3 possibilities

1. specify a field **name**

   name = fields.Char('loc', required=True)

or
2. add attribute _rec_name

```
_rec_name = 'loc'
```

Of course the field you will choose will be shown in the form.

or 3 add compute name function

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('line_type', 'loc', 'prod_type')
def name_get(self):
    result = []
    for linechargerule in self:
        result.append(
            (
                linechargerule.id,
                (
                    '{0} - {1} - {2}'.format(
                        linechargerule.line_type,
                        linechargerule.loc,
                        linechargerule.prod_type,
                    )
                ),
            )
        )
    return result
```

Comment: Sorry I didnt get - what I wanna is get the values from guimarc.linechargerule cost_element   and put it in a drop list, now what I have is only the IDS of these values not the value by itself.

Comment: But the answer is correct. Your model `guimarc.linechargerule` has no `name` attribute, so Odoo is using the model name and the ID as name representation in e.g. drop down lists (many2one fields). You have those three options in this answer, to get a better name representation. I would prefer a variant of option 1: change your `loc` field to `name`. Or just use option 2.